# What is offered for creating a SOAP server in WCF/services?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, service

I'm trying to develop an app that works with an existing soap client. I don't think it uses any WSDL/etc.  It just uses soap as a form of communication.

Example of what the client sends:

```
POST /SNSR_STD-SOAP HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "someCommand"
Host: 192.168.0.17:12345
Content-Length: 487
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!-- There is something in here obviously... -->
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

---

1. Now I want to be able to write a server that fetches those messages, gets the SOAPAction in the HTTP header and also the soap envelope/xml conviniently so I could reach all fields.

I started reading about WCF and services, and also followed MSDN getting started to WCF and server/client software, but it demonstrates creating a calculator service that works with wsdl etc, which is not the case here.

So the question - what is the preferred way of doing this? WCF? Services? How exactly do I launch the server, via IIS, maybe something else which is more automatic?

1. In the same manner, I need to write a soap client that sends such messages back to the client (which is now also a server).  How do I do that?

I need the simplest most elegant way for doing this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but you will have to work directly with the [Message class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.aspx) (look at [Message Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.headers.aspx) too) and use [Message Inspectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) to "intercept" the message at a lower level.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up, but can't I use a maybe more convinient WCF service with no possibility of offering WSDL file?